# Docker Container can't connect to the Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, etcd, docker-network

I have a on AWS EC2 Instances Docker Containers running, the Docker Containers are Connected over a Docker Network which is replicated over a etcd cluster. 
But all of the Containers can't connect outside. For example if I ping or curl a host get a 100% packages lost. 
The etcd network communicates over the AWS Private IP.

Here is my docker info:

```
root@ip-10-0-127-34:/home# docker info
Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 9
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-2050903-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 4.554GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 102.8GB
 Metadata Space Used:sattler 6.922MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.141GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 3.221GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.110 (2015-10-30)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1028-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.303GiB
Name: ip-10-0-127-34
ID: JFQO:C56I:VM22:UDKJ:QDKD:HUDT:KL3X:JCSR:WAPG:66JL:S4RM:4ENN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Cluster Store: etcd://127.0.0.1:2379
Cluster Advertise: 10.0.127.34:2376
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Docker Inspect the Network:

```
     {
    "Name": "df-global",
    "Id": "59aef8ccc5d7464ee715428783b9b03ba7737d298f41cc30a21f4856e75b92c1",
    "Created": "2017-08-14T09:51:31.650109966Z",
    "Scope": "global",
    "Driver": "overlay",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.1.0/14"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "Containers": {

     "ep-f257d697653d801395f9154d086a6290694d6ded7aefe827c67dcd10808023eb": {
            "Name": "elasticsearch-data-1",
            "EndpointID": "f257d697653d801395f9154d086a6290694d6ded7aefe827c67dcd10808023eb",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:0b",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.11/14",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ep-f5c1be7a768802154b58b33e67a3f009df1d4f1336297df9f914be9a720bd8ce": {
            "Name": "postgresql-vg_internal01-prod",
            "EndpointID": "f5c1be7a768802154b58b33e67a3f009df1d4f1336297df9f914be9a720bd8ce",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.2/14",
            "IPv6Address": ""
```

The same problem is described here: https://forums.docker.com/t/ping-between-containers-on-different-docker-host-but-connected-by-overlay-networ-fails/9960
but there is no answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was still able to `ping 172.17.2.1` and yet that was the only ip address I could contact from within a container.  Turns out someone/thing cleared out the iptables firewall and had every chain in every table replaced with default `ACCEPT` rules!  All the docker nat and forwarding rules were missing.  A quick reboot solved the issue.

A temporary solution was to use the docker command line option `--network 'host'`.

Answer (score 5):

Run on host machine:

```
sudo ip addr show docker0
```

You will get output which includes :

```
inet 172.17.2.1/16 scope global docker0
```

The docker host has the IP address 172.17.2.1 on the docker0 network interface.

Then start the container :

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:trusty bash
```

and run

```
ip addr show eth0
```

output will include :

```
inet 172.17.1.29/16 scope global eth0
```

Your container has the IP address 172.17.1.29. Now look at the routing table:
run:

```
route
```

output will include:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

It Means the IP Address of the docker host 172.17.2.1 is set as the default route and is accessible from your container.

try ping now to your host machine ip :

```
root@e21b5c211a0c:/# ping 172.17.2.1
PING 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.211 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
```

If this works most probably you'll be able to ping any public IP

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I try to ping the localhost I get a package lost of 100% and the information that the destination host is unreachable
`root@be845f307ee6:/# ping 172.17.2.1
PING 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.0.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.0.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 172.17.2.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4022ms
pipe 3`

Comment: Try the other answer .. if still no luck .. i ll help you to make your routes tables and networking fixed to able to ping host

Comment: I changed the Docker Network to  docker network create -d overlay --subnet 192.168.1.0/14 df-global
Now i can curl or ping google.com and sites outside, but if I try to connect or to ping to other containers in the network i get a package lost. 
For example ping db01-prod which is a docker container. And i see the container if i do docker network inspect NAME

Comment: These containers are part of same cluster ??

Comment: yes if i inspect the network you will find them
added it in the question

Comment: what probably you can do is .. create a network and connect all your containers to your network.

Comment: The containers already exists in the network. So with $ docker inspect NETWORK i see all the networks. 
But if I ping the container IP or the container Name i get a package lost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151878/discussion-between-shashi-bhushan-and-ghovat).

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative though .. if u dont want to mess around with networking routes ..so while running your container try Docker supports bind-mounting files from host to container. You can bind-mount the Docker control socket.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...usual code here...
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: I changed the Docker Network to docker network create -d overlay --subnet 192.168.1.0/14 df-global Now i can curl or ping google.com and sites outside, but if I try to connect or to ping to other containers in the network i get a package lost. For example ping db01-prod which is a docker container. And i see the container if i do docker network inspect NAME

Answer (score 1):

To allow containers to talk to each other : 
create a network

```
docker network create <your-network-name>
```

then connect all your containers to newly create network.

```
docker network connect <your-network-name> <containers>
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the answer. I created with this the network $ docker network create -d overlay --subnet 192.168.1.0/14 df-global and connected all the containers. 
In the docker network inspect NETWORK in the initial question you will see the connected containers but if I exec one of the containers and try to ping one of the other containers which is in the network I get a package loss of 100% and they cant communicate. Neither if I try the container name or the container IP from docker inspect